# Updating only some attributes of objects in cache

Tags: java, caching

Let's say I have a class `Item`. Items have object attributes and collection of other objects attributes:

```
public class Item
{
    //Object attributes
    String name;
    int id;
    Color color;

    //Collection of object attributes
    List<Parts> parts;
    Map<int,Owner> ownersById;
}
```

I have a fairly simple web application that allows crud operations on these items. This is split up into  separate operations:

- a page where you can update the simple object attributes (name, id...).
- a page where you can edit the collection of parts.
- a page where you can edit the map of owners.

Because the server load was getting too high, I implemented a cache in the application which holds the "most recently used item objects" with their simple attributes and their collection attributes.

Whenever an edit is made to the name of an item, I want to do the following do things:

- Persist the change to the item's name. This is done by converting the item object to xml (without any collection attributes) and calling a web service named "updateItemData".
- Update the current user's cache by updating the relevant item's nme inside the cache. This way the cache stays relevant  without having to load the item again after persisting it.

To do this I created the following method:

```
public void updateItem(Item itemWithoutCollectionData)
{
   WebServiceInvoker.updateItemService(itemWithoutCollectionData)

   Item cachedItemWithCollectionData = cache.getItemById(itemWithoutCollectionData.getId());

  cachedItemWithCollectionData.setName(itemWithoutCollectionData.getName());
  cachedItemWithCollectionData.setColor(itemWithoutCollectionData.getColor());

}
```

This method is very annoying because I have to copy the attributes one by one, because I cannot know beforehand which ones the user just updated. Bugs arised because the objects changed in one place but not in this piece of code. I can also not just do the following: `cachedItem = itemWithoutCollectionData;` because this would make me lose the collection information which is not present in the itemWithoutCollectionData variable.

Is there way to either:

- Perhaps by reflection, to iterate over all the non-collection attributes in a class and thus write the code in a way that it does not matter if future fields are added or removed in the Item class
- Find a way so that, if my Item class gains a new attribute, a warning is shown in the class that deals with the caching to signal "hey, you need to update me too!")?
- an alternative which might seem a bit overkill: wrap all the non-collection attributes in a class, for example ItemSimpleData and use that object instead of separate attributes. However, this doesn't work well with inheritance. How would you implement this method in the following structure?

classes:

```
public class BaseItem
{
    String name;
    int id;
}

public class ColoredItem
{
    Color color;
}
```

Comment: The class might have a constructor or basicCopy method handling copying all non-collection properties. That way it should be maintained when the class is extended. Or copy in full and call a method that empties all the collection properties.

Comment: using reflection you can call the corresponding setter on that object but trust me it's not an efficient solution if you're to do this often. I implemented it and then changed it back to normal copying. Anyways it's interesting to see any other approach for this :)

Answer (score 0):

There many things that can be done to enhance what you currently have but I am going to point out just two things that may help you with your problem.

Firstly, I am assuming that `public void updateItem` is a simplified version from your production code. So; make sure this method is thread safe, since it is a common source or problems when it comes to caching.

Secondly, you mentioned that

> Perhaps by reflection, to iterate over all the non-collection
>   attributes in a class and thus write the code in a way that it does
>   not matter if future fields are added or removed in the Item class.

If I understand the problem correctly; then, you can easily achieve this using BeanUtils.copyProperties() here is an example: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-copy-properties-from-pojo-to-other-java-beans/

I hope it helps.
Cheers,

Comment: Well, beanUtils.copyProperties could help if it would skip any properties that are null. Because if it doesn't, the null collections from the incomplete item object will overwrite the nonnull collections from the original item object.

Comment: Maybe, if you are using Spring you can do  org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties() with the ignoreProperties argument. Or BeanWrapper for more complex scenarios.